# How to order models from best to worst based on AIC from the result of lapply in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply, datalist, polynomials

Suppose I have following df.

```
ind1 <- rnorm(100)
ind2 <- rnorm(100)
ind3 <- rnorm(100)
ind4 <- rnorm(100)
ind5 <- rnorm(100)
dep <- rnorm(100, mean=ind1)

df <- data.frame(dep,ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)
```

I calculated 3rd order polynomial regression between dep variable and each of the ind variables separately using 
lapply() as follow:

```
polys <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(dep ~ poly(x, 3, raw = 
TRUE), data = df)))
```

Now I want to list/order best models based on AIC. I tried these without success.

```
stepAIC(polys)
polys$AIC
```

Do you have any idea how I should do this in R?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are conflating list objects with methods `stepAIC` and `AIC` that run on specific components. Specifically,

1. The function `stepAIC` in `MASS` package runs on individual model objects (e.g., `lm` class types), not summary of model objects and not list of model objects (i.e., *polys*) with your failed attempt: `stepAIC(polys)`.
2. The function `AIC` in `MASS` package runs on individual model objects usually after the `stepAIC` call and is not an item of the return with your failed attempt: `polys$AIC`.

Consider the following re-factoring of your code with seeded data for reproducibility to sort list of lm objects, *polys*, by ascending AIC values:

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(50619)    
#... same data build code ...

# LIST OF lm OBJECTS (NO SUMMARY)
polys <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) lm(dep ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df))

# SORTED VECTOR OF AIC VALUES (USING sapply)
AIC_vec <- sort(sapply(polys, function(x) AIC(stepAIC(x))))
AIC_vec
#     ind1     ind3     ind2     ind4     ind5 
# 297.1865 352.3694 352.8260 352.8260 352.8260

# SORTED polys BY AIC (BEST TO WORST)
sorted_polys <- polys[names(AIC_vec)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what I want. Can I make sure how I can see the result of sorted_polys? thank you for detail explanation on my failure as well.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. If inside an IDE like RStudio, simply call `sorted_polys` on its own line to see output. If running non-interactively like command line, wrap with print: `print(sorted_polys)`. Remember this is a named list of objects, so you use `$` qualifier on individual items: `sorted_polys$ind1`, `sorted_polys$ind2`, etc.

Comment: @ Parfait. I am sorry for bothering you again. I just observed 2 things regarding the calc. 1) the resulting values of AIC from "AIC_vect" is completely different than "AIC_vec <- ...".  In the output of AIC_vec <- ..., there isn't any such high numbers like 297.1865 etc. they all are around 70 something. 
as I understood, they should not be different. (second is as below)

Comment: 2) in the model list from best to the worst model list, models that don't have any significant correlation with dep are ranked as better model than the ones that have high correlation with "dep" when this polynomial regression checked separately to each independent variable. So I am quite confused why they are like these?

Comment: 1) What is *AIC_vect* (with a *t*)? Remember here we are using random normal data with defaults. 2) You only mentioned to rank order by AIC values without any mention of significance with *dep*. Extend `sapply` function to check for significance, possibly by p-value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```r
ind1 <- rnorm(100)
ind2 <- rnorm(100)
ind3 <- rnorm(100)
ind4 <- rnorm(100)
ind5 <- rnorm(100)
dep <- rnorm(100, mean=ind1)

df <- data.frame(dep,ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)

# Create all the models
polys <- lapply(df[,-1], function(x) (lm(dep ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df)))

# Find the best predictors using `setpAIC()`
mod <- lapply(polys, MASS::stepAIC)

# Calculate the AIC of each model and sort it increasingly.
i <- order(unlist(lapply(mod, AIC)))

# Show the models starting with the lowest AIC first
mod[i]
```

Comment: Any explanation? Code-only answers are not too intuitive.

Comment: @Philippe Massicotte. Thank you so much. when I run  mod <- , I got following results for each model where I am unable to descriminate which x variable is this. So is there any way to extract name of x variables as they are in df.  Start:  AIC=-5.29
dep ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)

                         Df Sum of Sq     RSS    AIC
<none>                                 87.555 -5.291
- poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)  3    96.303 183.857 62.899

Comment: What I want is to order the models by AIC from the lowest to highest (best to worst models).

Comment: Not true, `mod<-...` returns a named list of objects. Check with `names(mod)` and `names(mod[i])`. Notice they differ due to re-ordering.

Comment: I donwnovoted on the code-only lack of explanation.